# MongoDB, Return ingredients and amount/unit

Tags: mongodb

I want to make a query that returns only the fields "typ","tsk","dl" and "gram" in array "ingredienser" from this document:

I cant seem to figure out what syntax to use? $elemMatch with some sort of projection filter? Any help much appreciated!

```
{
    "bloggtyp": "recept",
    "rubrik": "MOROTSSOPPA",
    "gillar": 17,
    "kommentarer": 3,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    },{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-13",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "keeo"
    },{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-11",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "madad"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2012 - 04 - 23",
    "taggar": ["morötter", "soppa", "förrätter"],
    "tid": {
        "tillagning": 5,
        "på spisen": 30
    },
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "instruktioner": "Gör sa här: Skala morötterna – med din kropp! Koka i buljong.Salta och peppra efter tycke och smak.",

    "ingredienser": [{
        "typ": "Morötter",
        "gram": 500,
        "kcal/100g": 41
    }, {
        "typ": "buljong",
        "dl": 10,
        "kcal/100g": 128
    }, {
        "typ": "salt",
        "tsk": 1,
        "kcal/100g": 0
    }, {
        "typ": "peppar",
        "tsk": 1,
        "kcal/100g": 0
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below queries if you want to project all the items in the embedded document array.

Without Query Filter

```
db.collection.find( {}, { "ingredienser.typ": 1 ....comma separated rest of fields} )
```

With Query Filter (Multiple Conditions)

```
db.collection.find( {ingredienser: { $elemMatch: { typ: "buljong"....comma separated rest of fields } }}, { "ingredienser.typ": 1 .... rest of fields} )
```

With Query Filter (Single Condition)

```
db.collection.find( {ingredienser.typ": "buljong"}, { "ingredienser.typ": 1 .... rest of fields} )
```